# Create vertex groups (with names) when joining 2+ meshes

Tags: vertex-groups

Is there some what I can in 2.8:

Join multiple objects together to a single object (Ctrl-J) **and** use the original collection object names (Head,Arm.R,leg.R etc) to auto create vertex groups for each object (inside the new object)

I ask as I have a character who's parts are al cleanly separated as objects, parented , collection-ed and now I would like to rig it.

If there's a "right" way to move forward, I'd love to hear it, but I'd also love to solve this question too.

Comment: It seems that you are creating a workflow for yourself. I would suggest that you create a script that creates a vertex group on all your object naming it as you want and assign it to all the objects vertices. There are no such function in place but it shouldn't be too complicated to do.